# How does the decimal value '41000' convert to a floating point value of '0.0201'?

Tags: floating-point, binary, hex, converters

I am currently trying to change a 32 bit floating point value however the way that it was implemented only accepts UI32 integer values and will somehow convert it (can't change this conversion) to a floating point value and will display it. For example I can pass in `41000` and it will output/display `0.0201` though it stores up to 9 decimal places (3 more than that). The maximum and minimum values are defined in a .csv file with the max being `131070` (displays as `0.0627`) and the min being 0. The default value is `32767` which displays as `0.0157`.

I have tested decimal/integer to float using online converters but it doesn't seem to work (the value remains the same). It looks like it might be more than one conversion before arriving at a float value.

My question is what kind of conversion is going on here and is there anything I am not accounting for?

Any advice is appreciated!

Edit: Within the .csv file (that contains these values) I also found a scale number column and these values have a scale of `4.79*10^-7` which might be used to make the conversions instead of a integer to float conversion

Comment: Its probably in hexadecimal

Comment: What do you mean? Like convert from decimal to hex and then to floating point? Edit: Tested this and got `5.74532e-41` for `41000` which is way off. Maybe reading it wrong myself?

Comment: Do you have the source or documentation of that conversion function? Or do you try to reverse-engineer that?

Comment: There is not enough information here to answer. The three given samples (omitting the out-of-bounds 1015066128) are non-linear (by more than rounding for display can account for), so the converter is not merely multiplying by a scale (for a fixed-point format). The samples do not fit a normal floating-point format (e.g., 32767 would convert to something near a power of two times something like 1, 1½, 1¾, etc., regardless of where the exponent and significand fields were in the format, but it does not—it is a bit above 1/64). We would need more samples, routine names, documentation, etc.

Comment: Hi Eric. I have updated my question with a scale I found with these values. Sadly these are the only examples I have of this kind of implementation and sadly there is no documentation on this or any of the code I am working with (this is part of code developed 3-4 years ago and all of the developers have left).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using just the scale factor to multiply any integer point value to a 'floating point'. Very dodgy implementation but now I know why it wasn't a conversion.

Comment: Note that the scale factor is *almost* 2^(-21) = 4.76837e-7, hinting at the data being stored in a fixed-point format. What seems dodgy is the fact that the scale factor is subtly different at 4.79e-7, and as Eric Postpischil pointed out, the data presented in the question deviates from the linear relationship suggested by that scale factor.

Comment: Good pickup and I definitely noticed this as it did cause some inaccuracies but the output numbers get a lot of their decimal numbers cut off (only 6 decimal places). Thus this did not affect my outcome.